# Connected stabilisers for actions of reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a connected split reductive group over a field $k$ acting on a variety $X$ over $k$. For each $x\in X$, let $G_x$ be the stabiliser. In general, $G_x$ may be disconnected.

Now suppose $G$ and its Langlands dual $G^\vee$ have connected centre (examples include $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$, $E_8$, or $\mathrm{GSp}_{2n}$.

Question: Does it follow that $G_x$ is necessarily connected?

If it helps, we can assume further that $X$ is affine and that every $G$-orbit is closed (and that the ground characteristic is large).

Comment: I believe that your condition implies that the derived group of $G$ is simply connected.  In that case, stabilisers of semisimple elements (those elements of $G(k)$ with closed $G$-orbits) are automatically connected.  This is a result of Steinberg.  But perhaps you know this special case and are wondering whether it can be generalised?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, exactly.

Comment: Are you making some assumptions on $X$? Otherwise you can always take $X=G/H$, for any disconnected group with reductive connected component of the identity…

Comment: For which groups $G$ are the conditions satisfied?